# Issue with sending information from contact form

Tags: php

I am trying to send the values from a php form as email. When I set the `$message` to `var_export($_POST,true);` it exports the information but not in a easily readable way.

I have tried to set the values for each one as `$complain_detail = $_POST['complain_detail'];` but it stops the page from working or does not send the email.

```
    <?php
include 'main.php';
check_loggedin($pdo);
// output message (errors, etc)
$msg = '';

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($_POST['complain_type'] == null || $_POST['complain_title'] == null || $_POST['complain_issue_type'] == null || $_POST['complain_form'] == null || $_POST['complain_assigned_to'] == null || $_POST['complain_detail'] == null) {
        $msg    =   "Something missing, please input all required information.";
    } else {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT IGNORE INTO complains (id, complain_type, complain_from, complain_assigned_to, complain_title, complain_detail, complained_date, complain_issue_type, complain_status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
        $status = $stmt->execute(["", $_POST['complain_type'], $_POST['complain_form'], $_POST['complain_assigned_to'], $_POST['complain_title'], $_POST['complain_detail'], date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $_POST['complain_issue_type'], "Open"]);

        $complain_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
        
        $incident_record = $pdo->prepare('INSERT IGNORE INTO incident_record (id,complain_id, user_id, issue_date, assign_to, assign_by_client, record_type, record_details) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
        $status = $incident_record->execute(["", $complain_id , $_SESSION['id'], date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $_POST['complain_assigned_to'], $_POST['complain_form'], 'Created' , 'Complain Title: ' . $_POST['complain_title'] . ', Complain Details : ' . $_POST['complain_detail'] . ', Complain Issue Type : ' . $_POST['complain_issue_type']. ', Open' ]);

    $to_email = 'email@sdf.coms';
    $subject = 'New Incident Logged';
    $message = var_export($_POST,true);
    $headers = 'From: email@sdf.coms';
    mail($to_email,$subject,$message,$headers,"-f email@sdf.coms");

       
        $msg    =   "Incident has been loggged.";
    }
} else {
    $msg    =   "Whoops, something went wrong - Please try again.";
}

?>
```

Currently format is been sent as

```
array (   'complain_type' => 'WASP',   'complain_title' =>
'Test',   'complain_assigned_to' => '9',   'complain_issue_type' =>
'Support',   'complain_form' => '9',   'complain_detail' => 'Is this
better?',   'submit' => 'Submit Issue', )
```

I would like to to read as

> "A ticket has been opened under "type" and has been assigned to "user"
> "with description!

Comment: Can you show how is it looking alike now and how it should look alike?

Comment: I've added the comments to the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is an array, containing the request elements. Let's try to visualise it together...

If you have this HTML:

```html
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

And this `action.php` file:

```php
<?php var_dump($_POST);?>
```

The output will be the following:

```php
array(1) { ["name"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

So, in order to access the `name` value within the array, I need to call for `$_POST["element"]` where your element is the HTML `name` of the request parameter.

So, if in your HTML, the `message` is obtained with the following input:

```html
<input type="text" name="message" />
```

In order to properly retrieve it in your PHP code, you need to adjust the `$message` variable to be the following:

```php
$message = $_POST["message"];
```

Thus, you can concatenate your request parameters into your message variable like this:

```php
$message = "A ticket has been opened under " . $_POST["complain_type"] . " and has been assigned to user " . $_POST["complain_assigned_to"] . " with description " . $_POST["complain_detail"];
```